How do I turn off the focus point display in my viewfinder on the D7000?
After every picture when I look in the viewfinder to review it, there are red focus points shown. I want to turn that off.

When you open D7000 manual and go to page 197 you will see how in menu Display mode you can deselect focal point. This will prevent the view of the focal point during image review.
